# How to Add up multiple entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I work on a program that calculates the macros of each meal. You can enter a value in gram and it calculates for each aliment your intake. I would like now to add these values together when I push multiple buttons. Then I'll display the value somewhere and maybe I could do a graph after.

Here I show what my program looks like :

```
import tkinter as tk
    
def value_kiwi():
        value = ent_quantity.get()
        formula = (float(value)/100)
        cal = 53    
        pro = 1.6
        glu = 11.1
        li = 0.3
        Calories = (cal) * formula
        Protéines = (pro) * formula
        Glucides = (glu) * formula
        Lipides = (li) * formula
    
    
        lbl_cal["text"] =f"{Calories}"
        lbl_prot["text"] = f"{Protéines}"
        lbl_glu["text"] = f"{Glucides}"
        lbl_lip["text"] = f"{Lipides}"
    
    
def value_banane():
    value = ent_quantity.get()
    formula = (float(value)/100)
    cal = 90
    pro = 1.5
    glu = 20.1
    li = 0
    Calories = (cal) * formula
    Protéines = (pro) * formula
    Glucides = (glu) * formula
    Lipides = (li) * formula
    
    
    lbl_cal["text"] =f"{Calories}"
    lbl_prot["text"] = f"{Protéines}"
    lbl_glu["text"] = f"{Glucides}"
    lbl_lip["text"] = f"{Lipides}"
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Calculateur de Calories et Nutriments")
    
frm_entry = tk.Frame(master=window)
ent_quantity = tk.Entry(master=frm_entry, width=5)
ent_quantity.grid(row=1, column=0,)
    
lbl_cal = tk.Label(master=window)
lbl_cal.grid(row=1, column=1,)
    
lbl_prot = tk.Label(master=window)
lbl_prot.grid(row=1, column=2)
    
lbl_glu = tk.Label(master=window)
lbl_glu.grid(row=1, column=3)
    
lbl_lip = tk.Label(master=window)
lbl_lip.grid(row=1, column=4)

btn_kiwi = tk.Button(
    master=window,
    text="Kiwi",
    command=value_kiwi,
        )
    
btn_banane = tk.Button(
    master=window,
    text="Banane",
    command=value_banane,
        )
    
lbl_calories = tk.Label(master=window, text="Calories",)
lbl_proteines = tk.Label(master=window, text="Protéines")
lbl_glucides = tk.Label(master=window, text="Glucides")
lbl_lipides = tk.Label(master=window, text="Lipides")
lbl_fruits = tk.Label(master=window, text="Fruits")

frm_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
    
lbl_calories.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, sticky="w")
lbl_proteines.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
lbl_glucides.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)
lbl_lipides.grid(row=0,column =4, padx=10)
lbl_fruits.grid(row=1,column =5, padx=10)
    
btn_kiwi.grid(row=2, column=5, pady=10)
    
btn_banane.grid(row=3, column=5, pady=10)
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you're asking. To add up multiple entries you simply need to get the values, convert them to integers or floating point numbers, and add them together. What part of that are you struggling with?

Comment: When you put a value in the tk.Frame and push a button it calculates with a formula a value for each categories : Calories, Proteines, Glucides, Lipides. I want to add the banana and kiwi values together, when I push the buttons of each food.

Comment: _"I want to add the banana and kiwi values together,"_ - what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I don't understand how to do it automatically after I have entered a number in the entry. What I want to do is adding up the number together each time I push a new button. How do I tell the program to do that.

Comment: You can run the program and you will see what I mean to do, sorry if I'm not clear, I have troubles to express myself.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code

Comment: I don't understand how to tell the program " Each time a button is pushed, get the values resulting of the function associated in the command of the button and add together the values of each button"

The current code is working but I want to go one step further.

Comment: so You want a button that combines both existing buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I improved Your code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry, Label


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title('Nutrient calculator')

        # entry
        Label(self, text='Amount').grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.amount = Entry(self, width=5, bg='light grey')
        self.amount.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # calories
        Label(self, text='Calories').grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.calories = Label(self)
        self.calories.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # proteins
        Label(self, text='Proteins').grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.proteins = Label(self)
        self.proteins.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # glucose
        Label(self, text='Glucose').grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.glucose = Label(self)
        self.glucose.grid(row=1, column=3)

        # lipids
        Label(self, text='Lipids').grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.lipids = Label(self)
        self.lipids.grid(row=1, column=4)

        # list of all labels
        self.data_labels = [self.calories, self.proteins, self.glucose, self.lipids]

        # error label for if no value is entered or it cannot be converted
        self.error_label = Label(self, text='Use integer or float value!')

        # stuff for adding multiple foods
        self.do_add = False
        self.nutrient_list = []
        self.plus_btn = Button(self, text='Add', command=self.add)
        self.plus_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nwes')

    def display_values(self, value_list):
        self.nutrient_list.append(value_list)
        if len(self.nutrient_list) == 2 and not self.do_add:
            self.nutrient_list.pop(0)
        elif len(self.nutrient_list) > 2 and not self.do_add:
            self.nutrient_list = [self.nutrient_list[-1]]
        print(self.nutrient_list)

        if self.do_add:
            value_list = []
            for i in range(len(self.nutrient_list[0])):
                total_value = 0
                for item in self.nutrient_list:
                    total_value += item[i]
                value_list.append(total_value)

        for text, label in zip(value_list, self.data_labels):
            label.config(text=f'{text:.2f}')

        self.do_add = False

    def handle_value_error(self):
        self.error_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)

    def add(self):
        self.do_add = True
        self.amount.delete(0, 'end')


class Values:
    def __init__(self, name, row, column, calories, proteins, glucose, lipids):
        self.parent = root
        self.name = name
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

        self.calories = calories
        self.proteins = proteins
        self.glucose = glucose
        self.lipids = lipids

        self.stuff_list = [self.calories, self.proteins, self.glucose, self.lipids]

        self.button = Button(self.parent, text=self.name, command=self.set_values)
        self.button.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column, sticky='nwse')

    def set_values(self):
        value_list = []

        value_ = self.parent.amount.get()

        try:
            formula = float(value_) / 100

            self.parent.error_label.grid_forget()

            for item in self.stuff_list:
                item *= formula
                value_list.append(item)

            self.parent.display_values(value_list)

        except ValueError:
            self.parent.handle_value_error()


root = MainWindow()

kiwi = Values('Kiwi', 2, 4, calories=53, proteins=1.6, glucose=11.1, lipids=0.3)
banana = Values('Banana', 3, 4, calories=90, proteins=1.5, glucose=20.1, lipids=0)

root.mainloop()
```

it is not necessarily better however a few benefits from using this code are:

1. better organization (IMO) since it uses classes which make it pretty neat (however You have to have an understanding over them)
2. takes less space - what I mean is that now, to define a new food, You just have to initiate the `Values` class and give it the necessary arguments. You can take an example from the given instances.
3. possibly easier to expand (both because better organization and takes less space)

I edited the code so now it should have that functionality, the way it works is You choose an amount , then fruit and if You want to add more, press add button, then choose amount, press food and it will display the total so far, then again, if You want to add more press add and then put in an amount and press the fruit, currently the way to 'clear' is to press any food button and it should then reset the whole list and keep only the one that was just pressed and then repeat.

Comment: Thanks it's interesting how you did it, I'm a complete beginner so I'll need to study the code in depth. It looks way easier with the class Values. I think you understand what I want to do because I will add a lot of new foods. 
Now I need a way to calculate the total intake of calories, proteins, glucids, lipids if for example I eat 50g of Banana, 15 g of Kiwi, 100g of rice, or whatever quantity of whatever food.

Comment: @Lascarpas so You want a sort of a 'plus' ('+') button?

Comment: Yes exactly, this is what I want

Comment: @Lascarpas ok, I edited the code so now it should have that functionality, the way it works is You choose an amount , then fruit and if You want to add more, press add button, then choose amount, press food and it will display the total so far, then again, if You want to add more press add and then put in an amount and press the fruit, currently the way to 'clear' is to press any food button and it should then reset the whole list and keep only the one that was just pressed and then repeat

Comment: @Lascarpas also quick suggestion: make a sort of a dropdown list instead of adding a huge amount of buttons, or sth like that, but until its too big sure You can use buttons, also it is pretty important that You understand the code otherwise there is no point of using it, so ask questions if You have them

Comment: Thanks it works great, I never could have done that. I'll need some time to decrypt the whole code, because my understanding of the language is limited. It great for me to learn this way. I will come back to you soon.

Comment: @Lascarpas I suggest You don't think too much about the class part since most of it can be broken down to just simple variables and You can pretty much ignore the `self.` part, one thing tho, is that where You see the `self.parent`, in this case it is set to root (Values class's parent is root), so when using that You are essentially accessing the variables and methods defined in the MainWindow class